# Pulling out part of string(id or class) in Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have code like this.

```
<div class="market_listing_row number_490159191836499" id="number_490159191836499">
<div class="market_listing_row number_490159191836499" id="number_490159191836499">
<div class="market_listing_row number_490159170836499" id="number_490159170836499">
```

Is there a way to "pull out" part of things like class, id, name etc.
For example this marked number.
I have like 15 similar `id` on site(its always same patter,id="number_15digits") i want to pull out digits part and make it into list so I have all of them in one place.

id="number_**490159170836499**"

Comment: The answer to "is there a way" is almost always "yes". The more important question is "how". To answer this, you first need to define the pattern precisely. Depending on the complexity of the pattern you can use slices, string functions, or regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can locate all these elements by some common locator (this information is missing in your question) you can do something like this:

```py
import re

elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("your_locator")
for element in elements:
    id = element.get_attribute("id")
    id_number = re.findall('\d+', id)
```

The `id_number` will contain what you asked for

Comment: I tried using your method but there is problem since i get only one `id` repeated 27 times in list named `id`(27 is the lengh of that id located by me so i guess it has something to do with it).
I checked `elements` list and its for sure working with 50 different elements in it(every on site). I also used this code:
`for ii in elements:
    print(ii.get_attribute("id"))`

and its printing all `id` on site that im looking for so for sure `elements` list is gathering all of them.

Comment: Can you show me YOUR code where you getting these problems? Preferably not as a comment, to make it readable.. Also preferable please open a new question for it so that many people will see it and will be ably to help. If you will update this question only I will see it...

Comment: I posted it:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68967196/problems-while-trying-to-extract-part-of-id