# Problems while trying to extract part of id

Tags: python, selenium

so i tried to gather all of `ids` from site and "extract" numbers from them
Its looking like that on that site:

```
<div class="market_listing_row number_490159191836499" id="number_490159191836499">
<div class="market_listing_row number_490159191836499" id="number_490159191836499">
<div class="market_listing_row number_490159170836499" id="number_490159170836499">
```

So i located all of them using that xpath and to be sure printed lenght of that list(and all of elements in it while testing but deleted this part of code) so i know for sure its
working and collecting all of 50 different elements from site.

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[starts-with(@id, "number_") and not(contains(@id, "_name")) ]') 


print("List 2 lenght is:", len(elements))
```

But when i try to make list of numbers without "number_ " that id starts with i have problem. List called `id` that i create with get_attribute("id") is just one id(number_490159170836499 for example) repeated 22 times(its lenght of that id so it has to do something with it). `list_of_ids` is working as intended and i get 490159170836499 as result but its only one element(i guess its because theres only that number only repeated). Thats the code that i used:

```
for x in elements:
    id = x.get_attribute("id")
    list_of_ids = re.findall("\d+", id)
```

I also used this code to print all of `ids` on site so i know for sure that `elements` list have all of them in it and that get_attribute is working.

```
for ii in elements:
    print(ii.get_attribute("id"))
```

To be clear I did `import re`

Comment: can you show your command with where you removed `"number_`? Also, is it possible to see that web page? (Sharing the url)?

Comment: I will be better if you share ALL the relevant your code here. I guess there are some typo / mistake there

Comment: `list_of_ids = re.findall("\d+", id)` this is the part that removes "number_" and is supposed to create list of just digits. Also there is almost no more code that is relevant in this case. Its just importing few things, time.sleep(5) so my internet has time to load site and typical things like path and site link. The problem have to be the `id = x.get_attribute("id")` part since this list is just repeated id.

Comment: `x.get_attribute("id")` retrieves `id` attribute from already fetched web elements. As I understand `list_of_ids = re.findall("\d+", id)` is applied on attributes of already fetched elements too while the problem is with fetching the web elements with correct locator, I guess based on some XPath expression that you have changed.

Comment: `for ii in elements:
    print(ii.get_attribute("id"))`
The thing is this part prints all retrieved `id` with no problem from same list so i dont think there is problem with locator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another guess:

```
import re

ids = []
for x in elements:
    id = x.get_attribute("id")
    ids.append(re.search("\d+",id)[0])

print(ids)
```

Comment: I replaced `re.search` with `re.findall` and it works as i wanted it to.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You can use split method as well.

```
for x in elements:
       id = x.get_attribute("id")
       a =id.split("_")[1]
       print(a)
```